# getDocs function does not work in first run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get all docs from Firebase when user connect from `localhost:3000/` (it automatically redirects to `/profile`) but it does not work in the first run. Then when the page is refreshed by a user, it works. How can I run it in first try? Code below:

```
 try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "links"));
    await querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      if (stUser.uid == doc.data().uid) {
        links.push(doc.id);
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Redirects:

```
 function first() {
  if (!isLoggedIn.isLoggedIn) return <Redirect to="/auth" />;
     }
    function second() {
    if (isLoggedIn.isLoggedIn) return <Redirect to="/profile" />;
     }
    return (
    <div>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Redirect to="/auth" />
   </Route>
   {handleRoute(images)}
   <Route path="/auth" component={Dashboard}>
    {second()}
   </Route>
   <Route  strict path="/profile" component={HomePage}>
    {first()}
   </Route>
 </div>
 );
```

Comment: How does the information from `links` get rendered in the UI? You'll probably want to put that into the state with either `setState` or a `useState` hook. See some of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+usestate+is%3Aanswer+user%3A209103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not setting this variable in your state, as mentioned by Frank in the comments, so whatever changes you make to this variable might not be refreshed until actually force them by refreshing the page. I recommend you try something like the following code:

```
const updatedArray = links;
await querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  if (stUser.uid == doc.data().uid) {
    updatedArray.push(doc.id);
  }
});
setLinks(updatedArray);
```

Also, you will need to set this earlier in your code:

```
const [cars, setLinks] = useState([]);
```

finally, I would recommend you to check this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for a useState deepdive.